# Не могу в переменную занести значение из input

Tags: javascript, input

Вот весь код. Сколько бьюсь не помогает. Хочу что бы данные сохранились в переменную. По при выводе этой переменной (`alert`) получаю `undefined`.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('loginField').value;
function log_in_click(){
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\style.css" />
  <script src="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
  <form>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="loginField" placeholder="Login..." value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="passField" placeholder="Password..." class="inputs">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="log_in" class="button_login" onclick="log_in_click()">Login</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот вывод в `Chrome`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все потому-что вы берете значение переменной в момент ее инициализации.

Comment: @Duoxx поподробнее пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому-что вы берете значение переменной в момент ее инициализации, следовательно изначально в инпуте нет значения.

```js
function log_in_click(){
  var x = document.getElementById('loginField').value;
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\style.css" />
  <script src="D:\ВЛАД\Projects VisualStudio\Repositories\Сайты\MyWebSite\script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
  <form>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="loginField" placeholder="Login..." value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="passField" placeholder="Password..." class="inputs">
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="log_in" class="button_login" onclick="log_in_click()">Login</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```